# Regex for a particular string not working

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I have a string like this :

```
let input  = "Bldg ,32.9,-117.11,Yes,California,Yes,San Diego,,"San Diego, CA",123"
```

I need to split the string based on commas (",") but commas within quotes should be ignored. I tried to apply regex but in that case, the blank value is getting disappeared.

I need the following output

```
["Bldg",
"32.9", 
"-117.11", 
"Yes",
"California",
"Yes",
"San Diego",
"",
"San Diego, CA",
"123"
]
```

I have applied the following regex - `/[^",]+|"([^"]*)"/g` but that's not working.

Comment: Regular expressions are not the appropriate technique when you need to distinguish "inside" from "outside". They can't tell the difference between starting quotes and ending quotes.

Comment: You need to use a real parser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can match the regular expression

```
(?<=")[^"]*(?=")|(?<![^,])[^,"]*(?![^,])
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/N3F6fK/1)

The result of this match is the following.

```
["Bldg ", "32.9", "-117.11", "Yes", "California",
 "Yes", "San Diego", "", "San Diego, CA", "123"]
```

---

The regular expression has the following elements.

```
(?<=")      positive lookbehind asserts that previous character is a double-quote
[^"]*       match zero or more characters other than double quotes
(?=")       positive lookahead asserts that next character is a double-quote
|           or
(?<![^,])   negative lookbehind asserts that previous character is not a
            character other than a double-quote
[^,"]*      match zero or more characters other than commas and double-quotes
(?![^,])    negative lookahead asserts that next character is not a
            character other than a double-quote
```

Note that the double-negative, "negative lookbehind asserts that previous character is not a character other than a double-quote" is equivalent to asserting that the previous character is a double-quote or that the current character is at the beginning of the string. Similarly, "negative lookahead asserts that next character is not a character other than a double-quote" is equivalent to asserting that the next character is a double-quote or that the current character is at the end of the string.

Comment: In practice, a regex like this should almost never be used in production.  Write a parser instead.